# Can you replace a laptop screen with a different brand?

Tags: laptop, display, graphics-card, laptop-repair

hi i have two laptops sony Vaio and acer aspire 3 . the sony screen is broken and can i connect the acer screen to this sony laptop (both 40 pin/ but different resolution) ? . by the way i wanted to connect it for a short time just to see the bios menu.

Aspire 3 A315-33 series Model: N17C4 Cpu: intel cleron n3060 1.60 ghz Ram: 4gb ddr3 Gpu : intel hd 400 screen resolution: 1366x768

Sony vaio Product name: SVF1521USTW Model: svf152a29w Cpu: Intel Core i5-3337U Ram: 4gb ddr3 iGpu : intel hd 4000 dGpu: nvidia gt 740m screen resolution: 1600x900 (touch screen)

Comment: Can you not attach an external monitor? It has an HDMI port right?

Comment: When it is a linux operating system, I can connect to an external display with the hdmi port, but it does not reflect the bios or system splash screen.

Answer (score 1):

99.99% of the time that won't work. Even if all the wiring matches the laptop most likely doesn't know how to deal with the new screen.
And hooking it up can be quite tricky. Those connectors and the wiring are very fragile and are easily damaged.

Your best bet is to hook up an external monitor (or TV).. Most laptops will use that automatically when there is one attached and the internal screen is broken.

Comment: unfortunately no matter what i did Sony didn't show the bios screen in any way when i try connect external screen via hdmi

Comment: Why is the bios screen of a broken and very old laptop so important to you? It has been a while since last I dealt with any Vaio's but as far as I can remember there is next to nothing of interest in those Bios screens. This starts to sound like an XY problem.